# Gradient along object hair particles (like grass)?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, particles

I've spent way too many hours on this and I don't know how else to make this work. Perhaps a dozen hours went into getting the coordinates right on a group of grass, only for it to break completely when made into a particle (I thought this would not be an issue since it is generated from the "object" as you can see below). As for the original mesh, there is a special location that I have put my grass (under the ground) because I don't want to use a (useless) tilted object (seems to be the only way to get the particles to stay upright or they end up being on the side). Here's what I'm trying to do:

[image]

Here's what I get, though:

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated. Btw, I'm trying to do this (with the translucent-like effect):

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple problems arise from using the Object coordinates. I would use Vertex Colors:

In **Weight Paint** mode, use the *Weight Gradient* tool under **Weight Tools** in the <kbd>T</kbd> sidebar to create a weight gradient along your grass blade. Use the weight painting tools to adjust as needed:

[image]

Next, enable the **Tissue** add-on in the *Add-ons* panel of the user preferences:

[image]

Now, in **Vertex Paint** mode, use the *Vertex Color from Vertex Group* tool in the **Tissue Tools** panel of the <kbd>T</kbd> sidebar to convert the weight into a vertex group:

[image]

Last, use an *Attribute* node to get the gradient from the vertex color:

[image]

Result as a particle:

[image]

Comment: Awesome. Exactly what I was looking for. Lifesaver, man. I appreciate it!